# Can I modify my data model class so a query on a property does not cause an exception if there is no instance of the class?

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class DataSource
{
    [DisplayName("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

The following code to retrieve:

```
    public DataSource Get(string ds)
    {
        if (ds != null && ds == "0000")
            return GetDataSources().Single(s => s.Value == ds);
        return null;
    }
```

If the value of ds is null or "0000" then I need the following to 
return null but it gives an exception:

```
var dsa = _dataSource.GetTitle(ds).Title;
```

Is there something I could do to make the ".Title" return null rather than an exception if ds is null or "0000"?

Comment: is it `ds` that is `null`? or is it `_dataSource` ?

Comment: when the value of ds is null. If that happens the value of the DataSource retrieved is null and then when the ".Title" runs it gives an exception. If I try the code setting dsa without the .Title extension then it simply sets dsa to null and all's okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer would be a simple "no". What you are looking for is the "null safe dereference operator", which does not exist in C#.

There are a full things you can do, but to be honest I suspect the best option is simply: check the value before the member-access.

Other options:

- write an *extension method* (`GetTitle(this DataSource source) {...}`) that checks the `source` appropriately; extension methods *can* be called on `null` instances, so `GetTitle(ds).GetTitle()` will work even if `null` is returned
- use the ["null object pattern"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)

Comment: Thanks Marc. I'm marking as expected. Not quite sure how to do the extension method but I'll look into that now.